# Google Analytics not tracking clientside redirects

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to solve a problem with tracking traffic to individual blog posts on a system that uses a javascript redirect system where something somehow break tracking.

The way the system works is as follows:
Permalinks are in the format of `domain.com/ab_XXXXXX` where `ab_XXXXXX` is a unique code. That code is parsed by a piece of javascript, which tells the browser to load the individual blog post page. This page has a URL format of `blog.html/?cd_XXXXXX_ef=YYYYYY`. Here too, `XXXXXX` and `YYYYYY` are unique codes which, combined, identify the particular page.

When I load the `blog.html/?cd_XXXXXX_ef=YYYYYY` URL directly, Google Analytics does seem to track the page and the user shows up in the real-time dashboard as visiting that particular page.

However, when I load the `domain.com/ab_XXXXXX` URL, the user does not show up in Analytics' real time dashboard, even though the analytics tracking gif gets loaded.

Since the `ab_XXXXXX` URL is the permalink, Analytics appears to contain no data on individual blog post visits at all.

I'm not the programmer on this system, and at this point I'm not sure what to test or to suggest as changes to the programmers.

My question is: why would Analytics track the user in the one occasion, but not in the other? And what could be done to remedy this?

Comment: Hard to say what's the problem. Provide a link to your website..

Answer (score 0):

Does the page `ab_XXXXXX` actually redirect the user to `cd_XXXXXX_ef=YYYYYY` or does it simply load the contents of that blog post into the same page? In either case, but particularly the latter, you can simply choose to manually track the page view in your existing Javascript snipped by adding something along the lines of `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'blog.html/?cd_XXXXXX_ef=YYYYYY']);`

Comment: To answer David: it actually redirects. But the real answer turned out to be simpler (don't they always): someone had had the 'insight' to create an Analytics filter that rewrote any url containing html?* into html. rewriting the regular expression for that filter did the trick. Thanks David and Nikolay for taking the time to reply!